# PHP Laravel, edit blade file without re-compiling

Tags: php, laravel, ftp, laravel-blade

Disclaimer: I don't know php.

Hi.

I inherited a php project in laravel from a former employee. And now I need to edit a source file

index.blade.php

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://oldsource.com/"></script>
```

change it to a new source file, since we are changing hosting

They only provided me FTP access to the server, so I tried editing the blade file, but it won't reflect. Changing other assets such as images, or css files works. But change blade.php files show no changes

I think I need to re-compile it? Is there a way for me to change it with using FTP only...

I'm out of options, since even the network admin who previously handles it is nowhere to be found...

Need help.

Comment: You could try to run `php artisan view:clear` or `php artisan view:cache` (which might be hard with only FTP available)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiled views are stored in `/storage/framework/views`. Removing all files from this folder will force Laravel to recompile all views.

Comment: did this, but still not change... I try clear /storage/framework/session, but no change also

Comment: In that case you are probably editing the wrong view files. Can you update the question with what exactly you are changing?

Comment: ok, let me try edit all files to check, maybe im editing the wrong files, thanks for tip

Comment: You might also want to try and clear the `/storage/framework/cache` folder.

Answer (score 1):

you can use code to remove cache OR execute all cli commands like

```
Route::get('/clear', function() {
    $return = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    // return your message
});
```

if you have no cpanel access and possible you need to execute cli commands in future then you should read this [manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan#calling-commands-outside-of-cli)

Comment: Does it matter where do I execute that function? Can I put ut /routes/web.php ?

Comment: yes.... add into web.php file before auth.. and make sure after the execution comment this code